# How to save the user setting by using SharedPreferences?

Tags: notifications, sharedpreferences, settings

I made NotificationsActivity and I put 2 menu items to enable or disable receiving the notifications. When I changed the setting, and the notificiton become off, when I closed the activity and come back, it show notification on button, I have used SharedPreferences to save the setting in my app, but it did not work.

It should be on by defult, when the user changed to off, it should be show off button when he come back to the activity.

```java
public class NotificationsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationsActivity";
    Menu myMenu;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    public static final String mypreference = "true";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_notifications);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        Boolean on = pref.getBoolean("on", false);
        pref = getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(true),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (pref.getBoolean("on", true)) {
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(true);
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(false);
        } else {
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(true);
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(false);
        }
    }

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_notifications_on:
                myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(true);
                myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(false);
                editor.putBoolean("on", false);
                editor.apply();

                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("Offers")
                        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                            String msg = getString(R.string.notifications_off);
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                msg = getString(R.string.notifications_off_failed);
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, msg);
                            Toast.makeText(NotificationsActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        });
                return true;

            case R.id.action_notifications_off:
                myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(true);
                myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(false);
                editor.putBoolean("on", true);
                editor.apply();
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Offers")
                        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                            String msg = getString(R.string.notifications_on);
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                msg = getString(R.string.notifications_on_failed);
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, msg);
                            Toast.makeText(NotificationsActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        });
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing preferences to "MyPref" file and trying to read it from String.valueOf(true).

```
pref = getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(true),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

So the statement pref.getBoolean("on", true) will always return true and Notification will be On:

```
 if (pref.getBoolean("on", true)) {
        myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(true);
        myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(false);
    } else {
        myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(true);
        myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(false);
    }
```

Replace pref = getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(true),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE); in onCreate with below code:

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also, Please remove this line. It is not required.

```
Boolean on = pref.getBoolean("on", false);
```

Comment: I did what you said, but I got this error, Attempt to invoke interface 
method 'android. view. Menultem
android. View. Menu. Findltem(inty on a null
object reference

Comment: You are getting error because myMenu is not initialized and is null.

Comment: How to fix this issue?

Comment: Override  onCreateOptionsMenu if you are not doing it and assign myMenu inside it. See the code:
  
`@Override 
boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
      
  myMenu = menu;
      
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    
}`

Comment: okay. You are using myMenu in the onCreate function, at that time onCreateOptionsMenu isn't called so the myMenu is null. 
Remove this code 
       `if (pref.getBoolean("on", true)) {
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(true);
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(false);
        } else {
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(true);
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(false);
        }`

and place it after myMenu = menu this line.

Comment: So, I need to put this ~~~myMenu = menu~~~ in both. OnCreate and onCreateOptionsMenu? Or I put if condition code in onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: add it in onCreateOptionsMenu only and in OnCreate check myMenu should not be null before this code: if (pref.getBoolean("on", true)) {
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(true);
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(false);
        } else {
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_off).setVisible(true);
            myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications_on).setVisible(false);
        }